# How to make continuous video classification with Tensorflow Inception and raspberryPi?

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, raspberry-pi, neural-network, deep-learning

I have retrained Tensorflow inception image classification model on my own collected dataset and is working fine. Now, I want to make a continuous image classifier on a live camera video. I have a raspberry pi camera for input.

Here's I/O 2017 link(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZvccLwsMIWg&index=18&list=PLOU2XLYxmsIJqntMn36kS3y_lxKmQiaAS) I want to do the same as shown in the video at 3:20/8:49

Is there any tutorial to achieve this?

Comment: Perfect, and it sounds very cool, but I can´t see your code or where do you need help, or do you expect somebody to free-write and pin here all the code you are asking, without any effort from your side? [How to ask in StackOverflow](http://www.wikihow.com/Ask-a-Question-on-Stack-Overflow). Please re-ask your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Step one

Put your tensorflow model aside for this first step.  Follow different tutorials online [like this one](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/usage/camera/python/README.md) that show how to get an image from your raspberry pi.

You should be able to prove that your code works to yourself by displaying the images to a device or ftp'ing them to another computer that has a screen.

You should also be able to benchmark the rate at which you can capture images, and it should be about 5 per second or faster.

## Step two

Look up and integrate image resizing as needed.  Google and Stack Overflow are great places to search for how to do that.  Again, verify that you are able to resize the image to exactly what your tensorflow needs.

## Step three

copy over some of the images to your dev environment and verify that they work as is.

## Step four

ftp your trained tensorflow model to the pi along with installing supporting libraries.  Integrate the pieces into one codebase and turn it on.